# Насколько такое решение можно назвать хорошим ? Какое решение этой задачи можно считать эталонным?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, производительность, олимпиада

Задача:

> Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.
> If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".

Пример :

> Input: strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
> Output: "fl"

Моё решение:

```
string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs) 
    {
      
       std::sort(strs.begin(),strs.end(),
        [](const string& a, const string& b)
        { return a.length() < b.length(); });
        
        std::string answer = strs[0];
        if(strs.size() == 0)
            return "";
        std::size_t found;
        for (int i = 1; i < strs.size(); ++i)
        {
            found = strs[i].find(answer);
            if (found != 0)
            {
                answer = answer.substr(0,answer.length()-1);
                i = 0;
                continue;
            }
        }
        
        return answer;
    }
```

Серивс показал следующую оценку этого решения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В целом, вроде бы, неплохо. Но хотелось бы узнать насколько такое решение можно назвать хорошим?
есть ли у такого решения название ? (название алгоритма). Ну и собственно какой алгоритм для решения такой задачи можно назвать эталонным?

Comment: А что, решение засчитано верным? Оно работает на других примерах?

Comment: это LeetCode? там можно вкладку переключить и посмотреть решения других. А очень часто там бывают хорошие подсказки. Но вот substr частое - напрягает (память лишняя тратится)

Comment: @MBo Да, засчитано. Получается, что работает на всех примерах, которые заложены в автотесты

Comment: @KoVadim Да, он самый. Приведенные решения там на других языках, в частности на Java. Или Вы про обсуждения?

Comment: обсуждения. там очень часто бывает и на плюсах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, у меня вот это решение, основанное на простом переборе всех символов всех строк, начиная с первого (ну, и + некоторые частные случаи):

```
string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs)
{
    const int N = strs.size();
    if (N == 0) return "";
    if (N == 1) return strs[0];
    int l = 0;
    string s;
    for(;;++l)
    {
        char c = strs[0][l];
        if (c == 0) return s;
        bool ok = true;
        for(int i = N; i-->1;)
            if (strs[i][l] != c) { ok = false; break;}
        if (!ok) return s; else s += c;
    }
}
```

сказало, что

> Runtime: 0 ms, faster than 100.00% of C++ online submissions for Longest Common Prefix.
> Memory Usage: 9.2 MB, less than 77.26% of C++ online submissions for Longest Common Prefix.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но какое решение идеальное — я не знаю...

OK, чтоб снять лишние вопросы...

```
string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs)
{
    const int N = strs.size();
    if (N == 0) return "";
    if (N == 1) return strs[0];
    int l = 0;
    string s;
    s.reserve(strs[0].size());
    for(;;++l)
    {
        char c = strs[0][l];
        if (c == 0) return s;
        bool ok = true;
        for(int i = N; i-->1;)
            if (strs[i][l] != c) { ok = false; break;}
        if (!ok) return s; else s.push_back(c);
    }
}
```

Забавно, что это решение еще и уменьшило количество используемой памяти:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131412/discussion-on-answer-by-harry-------).

Answer (score 0):

NB: этот ответ существенно обновлён.

### Ответ на собственно вопрос

Ваш код обращается к первой строке до того как вы проверили размер вектора. LeetCode не проверяет пустой набор?

Сброс индекса `i = 0;` в теле цикла может привести к очень медленной (квадратичной) работе на специальных примерах. Но на LeetCode их нет.

Добавьте в ваше решение проверку

```
        if (strs.size() == 1)
            return strs[0];
```

это может сделать ваше решение идеальным (0ms). Видимо, есть отдельный тест с только одной длинной строкой.

Без сортировки можно обойтись. Опять таки из-за сортировки может снизится производительность на некоторых примерах, которых нет на LeetCode. Вместо сортировки отыщите самую короткую строку и поменяйте её с первой.

Вообще, на LeetCode дырявые тесты на этой задаче.

### Идеальное решение?

Решение ниже LeetCode иногда считает идеальным (0ms), а я считаю таким всегда. Сперва определим длину самой короткой строки. Дальше этой длины ходить не зачем. Проверим по столбцам что символы одинаковы. При обнаружении первого отличия выдадим ответ. К каждому символу обращение идёт только один раз:

```
class Solution {
public:
    string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs) {
        const vector<string>::size_type n = strs.size();
        if (n == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            return strs[0];
        }

        size_t min_size = strs[0].size();
        for (vector<string>::size_type j = 1; j < n; ++j) {
            min_size = std::min(min_size, strs[j].size());
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < min_size; ++i) {
            const char c = strs[0][i];
            for (vector<string>::size_type j = 1; j < n; ++j) {
                if (strs[j][i] != c) {
                    return strs[0].substr(0, i);
                }
            }
        }
        return strs[0].substr(0, min_size);
    }
};
```

Comment: Про сортировку. Например, мы имеем строку "flow" но обращаемся к ней так: `strs[i][l]`, и пусть, например, первое слово (по которому идет сверка) длиннее этого и в данном случае индекс l превысил 3. Тем самым мы обращаемся к символу, которого не существует. Это не вызовет ошибку? (как например, ошибка доступа к памяти, при обращении к элементу вектора, которого не существует).

Comment: @Artem.rtv, я переделал ответ. Игры с нулями до добра не довели. Там была тонкая ошибка, которая проявлялась на строках с нулевыми символами в теле. ЛитКоду это не важно, мне важно. Новое решение, чуть медленнее, так как я считаю минимальную длину среди всех строк. Зато я уверен что оно работает и работает быстро.

Comment: Не называйте свое решение идеальным. Даже Страуструп не осмелился бы.....

Comment: Слово не воробей...

Comment: 1) Гарантируется ли корректность работы функции, если количество элементов в векторе `strs` больше чем `INT_MAX`? 2) Гарантируется ли стандартом языка C++ что типы `std::size_t` и `std::string::size_type` равны? Если нет и в некоторой реализации они окажутся различными, то будет ли успешно скомпилирована функция?

Comment: @wоlolo, спасибо! Избавился от зависимости от INT_MAX. Да, стандарт гарантирует что `string::size_type` и `size_t` совпадают.