# Алгоритмы в Java

Tags: java, алгоритм

На собеседовании получил вопрос по символам в строке.
Есть массив строк

```
String [] source = {"ab", "abc", "abcde", "abf", "abd"};
```

Необходимо вернуть префикс, общий для всех элементов строкового масиива.

в приведенном случае -> ab

Не могу понять, как орагнизовать в коде. Все мои идеи из 3 и более циклов не получаются ((

Comment: Проблем... Сравниваем первые буквы. Если есть отличающиеся — префикс нулевой. Потом вторые. Потом третьи... Что тут сложного?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1348957/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be/1349001#1349001

Answer (score 3):

В цикле перебираем все возможные префиксы для первого элемента, а потом проверяем, есть ли этот префикс у остальных элементов.

```java
String [] source = {"ab", "abc", "abcde", "abf", "abd"};
boolean finish = false;
String prefix = "";
for (int i = 0; i < source[0].length(); i++) {
  Sctring curPrefix = source[0].substring(0, i + 1);
  for (int j = 1; j < source.length; j++) {
    if (!source[j].startsWith(curPrefix)) {
      finish = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (finish)
    break;
  prefix = curPrefix;
}
System.out.println("Prefix: ", prefix);
```

Проверок на ненулевую длину массива и на то, что массив не содержит `null`-элементов нет

Comment: А если короткое слово в середине? А не в начале? Надо сначала сделать поиск самой короткий строки в массиве

Comment: @ArtyMorris Если короткое слово посередине, то мы получим `finish = true;` как только длина префикса превысит длину этого элемента

Answer (score 3):

По мотивам комментариев от Arty Morris и Harry:

- находим длину самого короткого слова (это лучше, чем каждый раз проверять выход индекса за пределы слова)
- используя вложенные циклы: внешний - по символам, внутренний - по словам, ищем первое слово, в котором *i*-й символ будет отличаться от других.
- если во всех словах *i*-й символ одинаков, добавляем его в общий префикс.

```java
static String commonPrefix(String ... arr) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    int minSize = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToInt(str -> null == str ? -1 : str.length())
        .min()
        .orElse(0); // для пустого входного набора строк

    out: for (int i = 0; i < minSize; i++) {
        char curr = arr[0].charAt(i);
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j].charAt(i) != curr) {
                break out;
            }
        }
        sb.append(curr);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Тесты:

```java
System.out.println("'" + commonPrefix() + "'"); // -> ''
System.out.println(commonPrefix("source")); // -> source
System.out.println(commonPrefix("abcm", "abd", "abcde", "abcf", "abcd")); // -> ab
```

---

Версия с дополнительными проверками может выглядеть так:

```java
static String commonPrefix(String ... arr) {
    int minSize = null == arr ? 0 
        : Arrays.stream(arr)
            .mapToInt(str -> null == str ? -1 : str.length())
            .min().orElse(0);

    out: for (int i = 0; i < minSize; i++) {
        char curr = arr[0].charAt(i);
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j].charAt(i) != curr) {
                minSize = i;
                break out;
            }
        }
    }

    return minSize > 0 ? arr[0].substring(0, minSize) : "";
}
```